# Loop over 24-hour period using list of dates in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, python-datetime, datetime64

I have a list of `np.datetime64` dates in Python:

```
['2016-12-01T02:00:00.000000000', '2016-12-01T04:00:00.000000000',
 '2016-12-01T06:00:00.000000000', '2016-12-01T08:00:00.000000000',
 '2016-12-01T10:00:00.000000000', '2016-12-01T12:00:00.000000000', 
 '2016-12-01T14:00:00.000000000', '2016-12-01T16:00:00.000000000', 
 '2016-12-01T18:00:00.000000000', '2016-12-01T20:00:00.000000000', 
 '2016-12-01T22:00:00.000000000', '2016-12-02T00:00:00.000000000', 
 '2016-12-02T02:00:00.000000000', '2016-12-02T04:00:00.000000000', 
 '2016-12-02T06:00:00.000000000', '2016-12-02T08:00:00.000000000', 
 '2016-12-02T10:00:00.000000000', '2016-12-02T12:00:00.000000000', 
 '2016-12-02T14:00:00.000000000', '2016-12-02T16:00:00.000000000', 
 '2016-12-02T18:00:00.000000000', '2016-12-02T20:00:00.000000000', 
 '2016-12-02T22:00:00.000000000', '2016-12-03T00:00:00.000000000', 
 '2016-12-03T02:00:00.000000000', '2016-12-03T04:00:00.000000000',
 '2016-12-03T06:00:00.000000000', '2016-12-03T08:00:00.000000000', 
 '2016-12-03T10:00:00.000000000', '2016-12-03T12:00:00.000000000', 
 '2016-12-03T14:00:00.000000000', '2016-12-03T16:00:00.000000000', 
 '2016-12-03T18:00:00.000000000', '2016-12-03T20:00:00.000000000', 
 '2016-12-03T22:00:00.000000000']
```

and I wish to loop over each calendar day within the list. I have tried to extract each unique date from the list (i.e. finding the min and max date and creating a list of dates between these) but this isn't ideal for what I want to do.

**My desired outcome would be to have code that allows me to loop over each date/calendar day found in the list and obtain the datetimes corresponding to this date**:

```
for each_date in date_list:
    ***get all datetimes corresponding to each_date***

(loop would occur 3 times in this example)
```

NOTE:

1) Solutions that iterate over every [n:n+24] or whatever will not work as not every day will have the same number of time steps.

Comment: Are the timestamps *ordered*?

Comment: Yes... but solutions that iterate over every [n:n+24] or whatever will not work as not every day will have the same number of time steps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the timestamps are *ordered*, we can use the [**`itertools.groupby`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) function to group the elements of the array by the corresponding day.

The day can be obtained with `np.datetime64.astype(..., dtype='datetime64[D]')`, so we can write it like:

```
from numpy import datetime64
from functools import partial
from itertools import groupby

for day, timestamps in groupby(data_array,
                               partial(datetime64.astype, dtype='datetime64[D]')):
    # process day and timestamps
    pass
```

Here `day` is a `datetime64[D]` numpy object (it contains only the day), and `timestamps` is an *iterable* (not a list, but we can convert it to a list) of the corresponding timestamps. `data_array` is the array that contains the initial data.

For example:

```
>>> for day, timestamps in groupby(data_array,
...                                partial(datetime64.astype, dtype='datetime64[D]')):
...     print((day, list(timestamps)))
... 
(numpy.datetime64('2016-12-01'), [numpy.datetime64('2016-12-01T02:00:00.000000000'), numpy.datetime64('2016-12-01T04:00:00.000000000'), numpy.datetime64('2016-12-01T06:00:00.000000000'), numpy.datetime64('2016-12-01T08:00:00.000000000'), numpy.datetime64('2016-12-01T10:00:00.000000000'), numpy.datetime64('2016-12-01T12:00:00.000000000'), numpy.datetime64('2016-12-01T14:00:00.000000000'), numpy.datetime64('2016-12-01T16:00:00.000000000'), numpy.datetime64('2016-12-01T18:00:00.000000000'), numpy.datetime64('2016-12-01T20:00:00.000000000'), numpy.datetime64('2016-12-01T22:00:00.000000000')])
(numpy.datetime64('2016-12-02'), [numpy.datetime64('2016-12-02T00:00:00.000000000'), numpy.datetime64('2016-12-02T02:00:00.000000000'), numpy.datetime64('2016-12-02T04:00:00.000000000'), numpy.datetime64('2016-12-02T06:00:00.000000000'), numpy.datetime64('2016-12-02T08:00:00.000000000'), numpy.datetime64('2016-12-02T10:00:00.000000000'), numpy.datetime64('2016-12-02T12:00:00.000000000'), numpy.datetime64('2016-12-02T14:00:00.000000000'), numpy.datetime64('2016-12-02T16:00:00.000000000'), numpy.datetime64('2016-12-02T18:00:00.000000000'), numpy.datetime64('2016-12-02T20:00:00.000000000'), numpy.datetime64('2016-12-02T22:00:00.000000000')])
(numpy.datetime64('2016-12-03'), [numpy.datetime64('2016-12-03T00:00:00.000000000'), numpy.datetime64('2016-12-03T02:00:00.000000000'), numpy.datetime64('2016-12-03T04:00:00.000000000'), numpy.datetime64('2016-12-03T06:00:00.000000000'), numpy.datetime64('2016-12-03T08:00:00.000000000'), numpy.datetime64('2016-12-03T10:00:00.000000000'), numpy.datetime64('2016-12-03T12:00:00.000000000'), numpy.datetime64('2016-12-03T14:00:00.000000000'), numpy.datetime64('2016-12-03T16:00:00.000000000'), numpy.datetime64('2016-12-03T18:00:00.000000000'), numpy.datetime64('2016-12-03T20:00:00.000000000'), numpy.datetime64('2016-12-03T22:00:00.000000000')])
```

So here for every day, we have opted to print a list of corresponding `timestamps`, but this is of course *one* of the options. Like the example shows, not all slices have the same length (the last two have an extra element)

Note that the `timestamps` is an iterator, and thus gets exhausted, if you do not convert it to a list, then after one loop, the iterator is *exhausted*.

The `groupby` works in linear time, since each time it checks if the "group key" is the same as the previous element, but as said before the contraint is data must be ordered.

Comment: Perfect! Plus works for dates with potentially different number of time steps, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `collections.defaultdict` for an O(n) solution. You can use Pandas to normalize your `datetime` objects, although this should also be possible via NumPy.

```
import pandas as pd
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)

for item in L:
    day = pd.to_datetime(item).normalize().to_datetime64()
    d[day].append(item)

print(d)

defaultdict(list,
            {numpy.datetime64('2016-12-01T00:00:00.000000000'):
                 [numpy.datetime64('2016-12-01T02:00:00.000000000'),
                  ...
                  numpy.datetime64('2016-12-01T22:00:00.000000000')],
             numpy.datetime64('2016-12-02T00:00:00.000000000'):
                 [numpy.datetime64('2016-12-02T00:00:00.000000000'),
                  ...
                  numpy.datetime64('2016-12-02T22:00:00.000000000')],
             numpy.datetime64('2016-12-03T00:00:00.000000000'):
                 [numpy.datetime64('2016-12-03T00:00:00.000000000'),
                  ...
                  numpy.datetime64('2016-12-03T22:00:00.000000000')]})
```